# The Lord of Destruction is dead

Tags: bug, status-completed, diablo-3

From the contest website (emphasis added):

> [...] a series of Acts and Gems you can earn to aid you as you set out to battle the **Lord of Destruction**. [...]

As far as we know from *Diablo II*, the Lord of Destruction (Baal) is dead.  This statement is either inaccurate or a spoiler. `):` The main antagonist (at least up front) is Azmodan, a Lesser Evil.

<sup>(FWIW I reworded it on the meta post to "minions of Hell")</sup>

Comment: And Diablo is the Lord of **Terror.**

Comment: @RavenDreamer presumably he's "dead" from D2 (though he does show up), maybe "LoT's armies" or something.

Comment: I was thinking something like "... to battle the (onslaught of) demonic legions pouring out from the depths of the Burning Hells."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! "Lord of Destruction" has been swapped with "minions of Hell".